# GAE Search API: How to prevent the 2000 bytes query limit?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, search, google-search-api

We are using the GAE Search API since quite some time but recently hit the query length limit of 2000 bytes:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: query string must not be longer
>   than 2000 bytes, was 2384

We're basically having documents saved with a secondary id set as an atomic field. Within our query we do some sorting and distance calculations and also exclude docs with those secondary ids matching a list of ids with a NOT statement like following:

```
... AND NOT sec_id:(x AND y AND ...)
```

With a certain amount of excluded ids we obviously hit the query length limit. I could split the query into separate ones with the same base query and only use a different set of excluded ids but then the sorting is problematic.

So I am wondering if there is another way to implement this kind of query, preferably with a black and also a white list within one query (AND NOT :(..) & AND :(..)).

Comment: i think you will need to manually filter them out post-query and exclude as many as you can in the query.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well, but it is not scalable since it gets a lot more over time. In our specific case sec_id is the user id of that document the user posted and the white list would be a list of user ids the requesting user is following.

Comment: IMO what's not scalable is the way you check for ids, not the datastore query itself because there is no way arround having to check each. the only way to keep that scheme but do it on constant time is to mapreduce it with appengine.